# Python 3.x tkinter comboboxes syncing ['variables']

Tags: python, python-3.x, combobox, tkinter, synchronization

I am trying to have multiple (two for this example) ttk.Comboboxes with unique variables. The boxes are syncing my selection rather than allowing me to select individual variables.

I am using a main file and an import to store the variable:

**list.py** (the variables)

```
class object():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = ['a','b','c']
```

**main.py** (the program):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

import list

root = Tk()

aList = list.object('aName')
bList = list.object('bName')

aVariable = aList.list
aCombobox = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=aVariable)
aCombobox['values'] = aList.list
aCombobox.grid()

bVariable = bList.list
bCombobox = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=bList.list)
bCombobox['values'] = bList.list
bCombobox.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

importing the variables (as a module/class) and initializing each (aList and bList) I figure would create two separate objects. Each Combobox has its own *textvariable* and generates its ['valuse'] from the created objects. However, this does not work - they keep syncing.

I was able to get it to work in an interactive session as well as a CLI application:

**list.py** (same import as above)

**main.py** (as a console - no tkinter)

```
import list

a = list.object('list')
b = list.object('list')

print(a.list, b.list)

b.list.pop()

print(a.list, b.list)

input()
```

I've also tried copy.copy() and copy.deepcopy() but neither work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use ordinary variables as the value of the `textvariable` attribute. You'll need to use a tkinter variable -- typically an instance of `StringVar`. For more information see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm